# How would I improve the performance in the following scenario

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a Table, with certain number of columns, I have applied a certain algorithm and was able to divide the existing Table into 5 tables. Here is the image of the databases after the application of algorithm. 
[image]
 So I have divided the stsi table into base, card_type, country, cvv, . The STSI had the following attributes .. id, name, phone, email, branch, country, ac_no, credit_card, card_type, cvv. So after the application of the algorithm, The base table has the id, name, email, branch, ac_no, credit_card, phone. And the remaining attributes are   card_type, country and cvv. These attributes are given a separate table each. Let's say for the tale cvv. The attributes will be id and cvv. The id will be a `primary_key` to the base table. So as per the image I was able to reduce the number of rows in the newer tables formed **since cvv has 7829 rows instead of 9000 as in STSI, because of the nulls in STSI**. The performance was increased with respect to space. But I am unable to increase the time complexity.

> I intended that newer tables should have lesser time complexity, as they have relatively lesser number of rows. But I am not able to get any performance increase. I have tried indexing, but it did not result in any performance gain. what can I possibly do for increase in performance with respect to time, when executed on new tables.

ps: The queries are 
`select id,cvv from stsi - 0.0005 seconds
 select id,cvv from cvv - 0.0005 seconds` 
I am hoping that second query should take lesser time!

Comment: Please post the query that has low performance.

Comment: The queries are showing equal performance in STSI as well as Newer tables. `Say select cvv from STSI , select cvv from cvv` are giving the same times

Comment: .5 milliseconds is not a performance issue, and your "optimization" is complete overkill.

Comment: I know 5 milliseconds is not an issue, but in theory, the performance should get improve right? @alex

Comment: You won't see the difference between 10 nanoseconds and 15 nanoseconds sql execution time when serving the data back to PHP requires 400 nanoseconds.

Comment: so you mean to say that I should have a bigger database? @alex .. can you provide me a source on 400 nanoseconds thing?

Comment: @gates try with the larger database. 9000 rows is very small as compared. Just give a try with 100000 rows.

Comment: select * from table performs at the speed of your disks/disk caching subsystem.  if all of the rows fit into the disk cache then reducing the number of rows will not make that much difference.

Comment: So how many rows would not fit once into a disk cache at once? @ChrisK

Comment: A normal hard disk has a cache of no more than 64MB, and 9000 rows have 1.5meg. Go figure.

Comment: Where do you get this data from? 9000 rows, and in previous comment 400 ns!

Comment: @VamsiPavanMahesh it really depends on your hard disk (for built in cache), OS settings and data base settings (as main memory can also be used as page caches for memory/disks).  You will have to dig a bit, however I would start by asking the DB how much disk i/o was performed by the queries.  I suspect that in both of your cases, it will be a similar number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At 0.5ms, its likely the limiter is actual system response time (disk read, CPU processing, etc) and not the query itself. No amount of optimization is going to reduce that response time.

As a general rule, when you are looking at simple select queries (select val1, val2 from table), the biggest driver of performance is going to be the underlying system configuration (disk configuration and memory availability mainly) and database design.

Using good indexing can help query response time by reducing the amount of data that has to be read to produce results. In the above example, placing an index on the CCV table consisting of ID and CCV would likely yield a faster response as your dataset grows.

I assume, based on your bolding, that your question stems of the fact that STSI has more rows than CCV and you expected CCV to be faster. The reality is that you are likely seeing the first constraint here (system configuration) and not database design.

Half a millisecond is damn fast. I dont know that you should expect to see anything faster on consumer grade hardware even if you were comparing a 9000 row table to a 9 row table.

Comment: Yes, I agree with most of your points. And yes, mine's a laptop, which is again consumer grade. As per the timing concerned, 0.5 milliseconds is fast. so I want to turn this a bit, is there any way I can reduce the response time of STSI? I know this kinda beats the point of this. But I want to know if there is a way exists! @tdavis

Comment: You could try adding an index to STSI on just ID and CCV, but i doubt you will see any difference.

Comment: I tried, but no difference as you mentioned. But at what point will I able to see a aggreable difference. Like 1 million dataset, Amazon instance, anything?

Comment: Once your dataset grows past the point of being able to be held entirely in cache. This will be system dependant. generally speaking, over 100k rows of data will be needed to start seeing significant performance differences

Comment: 0.5ms probably means that the result came from the Query Cache.  So the time is bogus.